# Tailwind custom utility class - duration not working

Tags: html, css

I have problem with duration in tailwind. I made custom CSS class in main input.css file and add this to html code. Unfortunately duration-300 dont work with this custom class. Can somebody help me and tell me how to fix this problem ? I will be very grateful.

Greetings

I tried to add transition-duration to custom class, add duration to group-hover and put it into different html tag but nothing helps.

```css
@layer utilities {
    .orangefilter {
        filter: invert(55%) sepia(29%) saturate(5825%) hue-rotate(352deg) brightness(102%) contrast(90%);
    }
}
```

```html
<li class="flex justify-center items-center group hover:text-orange-400 duration-300 ">
    <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-2 contrast-50 group-hover:orangefilter duration-300" src="./icons/user.png">
    <p>Account</p>
</li>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Corrected, im new here

Comment: Can you post sufficient code to reproduce the problem? For example In a way we can copy and paste into here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/

Comment: Paulo, example here - https://play.tailwindcss.com/1LhqwDRPJO